# How can it be that a Twitter message is viewable individually but invisible in a user's timeline?

Tags: twitter

Although a message is being accessible through a link, it doesn't appear in a person's timeline at the date-appropriate place. I wonder how that can be explained?

Answer (score 1):

Embarassing, the tweets that I couldn't find on a user's profile page are found in the 'Tweets & Replies' section. Sorry.